# OpenLayers - Features in cloned layer changes style with original feature

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, features, style

Please help!

My situation is that, I clone() a "newLayer" from an "oldLayer" with its features. Both of them seems correct at first. But then when I tried to change the style of "featureA" in the "oldLayer", the cloned "featureA" inside the "newLayer" changes too after redraw() is called. Is it possible to "unlink" them, they seems attached to the same style object and caused this problem.

I've been looked around for a whole day and tried all I've found, but still no luck. Anyone can help? Thanks a lot. And sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Can anyone help ... ? :(

Comment: Problem solved by cloning the style object separately and reset it to the cloned feature. :-)